# cannot install APC with PECL & PHP 5.5.9

Tags: php, homebrew, pecl

I have installed PHP(5.5.9) via Homebrew(0.9.5), and I can't seem to install any packages with   `pecl`. For instance when I try to install `APC` with `sudo pecl install apc` I got the following string returned:

```
WARNING: php_bin /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.9/bin/php appears to have a 
suffix 55/5.5.9/bin/php, but config variable php_suffix does not match
```

If I just ignore the warning and proceed, at the end it fails with:

```
2 warnings and 6 errors generated.
make: *** [apc_compile.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I have `make` installed via homebrew as well as `pecl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APC is outdated, and has never been updated/released for PHP 5.5.
Since version 5.5, PHP comes with it's own opcache.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php

Comment: This does not really help with my initial question, but I will look at what you linked to. I am looking for more of a resolution to installing extensions via `pecl`, as that is what my problem is.

Comment: @BrandonDavis You only mentioned problems installing APC, it has 2 compiler errors (which is what I would expect, since it isn't supported for PHP 5.5), but you didn't post those. If you have problems with other $random pecl packages, then please update your post with the **full** output of your command, and I (or someone else) may be able to provide a more useful answer for you :-)

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct in that with PHP 5.5 it will not work. I tried with PHP 5.4.20 PECL and it worked well.